# input file with python 3 EOF

Tags: python, linux

in a windows terminal, one types: `python3 program.py<input_file.txt` to run a program using a text-input file.
I'm new to Linux and I have tried this, and I get the error:

```
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
```

Any suggestions as to why it's reading my input file as a string? Any help will be much obliged!

Comment: Please post the source code. The problem is not in the command line.

Comment: Is that the complete error? That almost certainly looks like only a part of it. Also, what are [example contents](http://sscce.org/) of `program.py` and `input_file.txt` that lead to this problem?

Comment: Python isn't reading your `input_file.txt` as a string. The shell is feeding `input_file.txt` as the standard input to Python, and Python just hands that off to your script, just like in Windows.

Comment: Voting to close as not reproducible. The question is years old and does not have a proper [mre] nor a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message. *If the guess in the accepted answer was correct*, then this is a common duplicate, and not a good signpost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wild guess. You are using python3 in Windows, but you are using python2 in Linux. Also, you have an `input()` function call in your program. You are caught in an incompatible change between python2 and python3.

You can confirm my suspicion by running `python -V` in each environment.

If I am right, you can solve the problem by replacing your `input()` with `raw_input()`, or installing python3 on Linux.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I have downloaded and installed 3.3.1 on both machines, but I'm guessing it hasn't taken the place of 2.7 on my Linux machine.